# Use properties in props/csproj files in C# code

Tags: c#, msbuild

Say I have a property SomeValue declared in my csproj file or in a props file.

Is there a way I can reference that property in my C# code?

Comment: Can be confusing when coming from a C-like background but C# doesn't have a preprocessor like C or C++ does where you can tell the compiler to set certain symbols to certain values, so no, there's no way to directly reference msbuild properties. Only something like Filburt's answer will work.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a pre-build task to inject the value into your code but there is no way to reference a property because the project file is not part of the code - it's just a container for your code holding some properties that are used for templating your code files like for example the default namespace of your project that gets added to code files automatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you have old style .net framework project, then create first new .net core project (which has `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"` tag in it), replace `TargetFramework` with the one you used, for example:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  <PropertyGroup>
```

After it compiles and works correctly - then you need to add nuget `RoslynCodeTaskFactory` package - you can do that either from UI or by directly editing project as a xml file (Right click on project will have `Edit project` option).

```
  <ItemGroup>

... other PackageReferences ...

    <PackageReference Include="RoslynCodeTaskFactory" Version="2.0.7" PrivateAssets="All" />

... other PackageReferences ...

  </ItemGroup>
```

And then add generating of .cs code, for example like this:

```
<Project InitialTargets="ValidateContentFiles" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" ToolsVersion="15.0">

   ...

  <!-- Run-time generated file, based on build_info.props properties -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Autogenerated.cs" Condition="!Exists('$(ProjectDir)Autogenerated.cs')" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="$(ProjectDir)\build_info.props" />

  <UsingTask TaskName="GenerateFile" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(RoslynCodeTaskFactory)" Condition=" '$(RoslynCodeTaskFactory)' != ''">
      <ParameterGroup>
        <Filename ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      </ParameterGroup>

      <Task>
        <Reference Include="System.Core" />
        <Using Namespace="System" />
        <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
        <Code Type="Fragment" Language="C#">
          <![CDATA[
            String context = "";
            
            var value = "$(YourProperty)";
            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) )
            {
              value = "Default fallback if value was not specified";
            }
            
            //Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, $"file: {Filename} value: {value}");
            if( File.Exists(Filename) )
            {
                context = File.ReadAllText(Filename);
            }
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("// Autogenerated by .csproj file. Do not edit, your modifications will be lost after generating file again");
            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.AppendLine("namespace yournamespace {");
            sb.AppendLine("    public static partial class YourClassName {");
            sb.AppendLine($"        public static readonly string YourPropertyKey = \"{value}\";");
            sb.AppendLine("    }");
            sb.AppendLine("}");
            
            if(sb.ToString() != context)
            {
                //Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, $"Saving file '{Filename}'");
                File.WriteAllText(Filename, sb.ToString());
            }
          ]]>
        </Code>
      </Task>
  </UsingTask>
  
  <Target Name="ValidateContentFiles">
    <GenerateFile Filename="$(ProjectDir)Autogenerated.cs" Condition=" '$(RoslynCodeTaskFactory)' != ''" />
  </Target>
```

Please note that `InitialTargets` will be executed before project is built, so you might not see `Log.LogMessage` even thus it's executing indeed.

If you have some mistake in the code itself - most probably you will not see any error about it , so try to add one line at the time.

And after that you can reference your property using `yournamespace.YourClassName.YourPropertyKey`.